# How to make an asynchronous process as synchronous in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, eslint-plugin

I am currently developing a plugin for eslint. I have encountered the following problem.
I want to make hot changes to the configuration file, so we are required to make an Http request to get the JSON file with the configuration.

As for the context execution when reading the package.json, and traversing the scripts, when adding async/await, it executes in node the code, but does not return the context response from the context object.

If I do it with callbacks exactly the same thing happens. I leave you the code so that you have a visual idea of the problem.

With Promises using then(), catch(), doesnt works too.

I think that what I am asking for in the JavaScript world is not possible, but by asking I don't lose anything. I understand that the functions like execSync, are native inside the C core written in JavaScript, and that's why they can be executed synchronously.

Thanks and greetings.

```
'use strict';
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Meta Definition
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const meta = {
  type: 'problem',
  docs: {
    description: `Rule to don't allow changes in scope scripts of package.json`,
    category: 'Possible Errors'
  },
  schema: [
    {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        alternatives: {
          type: 'object',
          patternProperties: {
            '^.+$': { type: 'string' }
          }
        }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    }
  ]
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rule Definition
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const TEST_CONTENT = 'jest';

const isPackageJsonFile = filePath => filePath.includes('package.json');

module.exports = {
  meta,
  create: (context) => {

    return {
      'Program:exit': async node => {
        if (!isPackageJsonFile(context.getFilename())) {
          return;
        }
    const packageJsonRaw = readFileSync(context.getFilename(), 'utf8');
    const packageJson = JSON.parse(packageJsonRaw );

    // Peticion async / await
    const testScript = await httpRequest.getJSONFromURL().test || TEST_CONTENT;

    if (!packageJson.scripts || packageJson.scripts.test !== TEST_CONTENT) {
    context.report({
      message: `Dont allow changes on script "scripts.test" of package.json`,
       node
    }); 
       }     
      }
    }

  }
};
```

A way to be able to return the result of the http request, like fileReadSync but without callbacks because it doesn't work, is it possible, I can't think how to do it.

The implementation that I have made at the moment, I make use of child_process with curl, with an execSync, and with that I have managed to make it work, but the truth is that I am not convinced at all by this implementation.

Comment: Why must it be synchronous?

Comment: You cannot make an asynchronous operation in Javascript into a synchronous one other than the hack of using something like `execSync()`.  That's the only way to do it.  Much better to clean up the design so that it can have an asynchronous interface.  Return a promise that resolves with the final value when the operation is complete and let the caller use that promise to know when things are done and get the value.

Comment: Must be sync because its for a eslint plugin, and doesnt works with async or callback functions the context.report @KevinB

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, im agree with u.

Answer (score -2):

try this simple way of promising

```
async function doB(){
  try{
  const res = await CertainPromise() 
  return res.json();//something
 }catch(e){}
}
```

This should actually work;

Comment: That's still asynchronous.

Comment: Men i told that promises, or callbacks doesnt works lol.